# Object format and return empty string in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 and entity framework, I am retrieving emails from the server:

```
var data = db.Candidates.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID) && c.Email1 != null).Select(c => new { c.Email1, c.ID }).ToList();
```

My first question: Does LINQ allow me to return an empty string form the Email1 field if it is null, similar to SQL coalesce? (I would remove the null test from the where clause).

2nd question: what would be the easiest object to use (to replace the "var data =" if I wanted to get c.Name along with the Email1, then use both in a loop? Should I create a model for just 2 fields?

Thanks so much in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first question: Does LINQ allow me to return an empty string form the Email1 field if it is null, similar to SQL coalesce? (I would remove the null test from the where clause).

Yes, there is the `??` operator that works similar to the `coalesce`.:

```
new { Email1 = c.Email1 ?? "", c.ID } //String.Empty would be nicer, but i think it depends on EF version if you are allowed to use it.
```

For your second question, if this is the only place you are going to use them, then anonymous is pretty fine.
If you want to use this on other places, yes create an object just with two properties... That's the object's purpose after all. (or maybe a struct?)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask one question at a time.

2a. The Null Coalescence operator in C# is [`??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

2b. This may or may not be converted by your Linq Provider into a database query.

3. Do it like this,

   ```
   var data = db.Candidates
       .Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID))
       .Select(c => new
           {
               Id = c.Id,
               Email1 = c.Email1 ?? string.Empty,
               Name = c.Name 
           });

   foreach(var row in data)
   {
       var name = row.Name // etc...
   }
   ```

If your Linq Provider does not support the `??` operator, put in a `.ToList()` and use linq-to-objects to perform the tranformation like this,

```
var data = db.Candidates
    .Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID))
    .ToList() // <-- from here is Linq-To-Objects
    .Select(c => new
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Email1 = c.Email1 ?? string.Empty,
            Name = c.Name 
        });
```